# SignByCert returning signature of length 264 for 2048 bit keys

Tags: sql-server, digital-signature, sql-server-2017

We have recently migrated to SQL Server 2017 (64 bit - version: 14.0.1000.169 - Host OS: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter). I created the test certificate in database and used it to sign sample text. The SQL method SignByCert returned signature of length 264 bytes.

Ideally I expect the signature size should be length of mod length which is 2048 bits (256 bytes) in my case. I am wondering why the SignByCert returned signature of length 264.

Below is sample code.....

```
Create certificate MyTestCertificate
with Subject='MyTestCertificate',
EXPIRY_DATE = '20231010' ;

DECLARE @ClearText as varchar(8000); 
DECLARE @Signature as varbinary(max); 
DECLARE @Signature_len as int;
DECLARE @RESULT as int;
SET @ClearText = 'This is some clear text to encrypt';
SET @Signature = SignByCert(Cert_ID('MyTestCertificate'), @ClearText);
SET @Signature_len = datalength(@Signature) ;

SET @RESULT = VerifySignedByCert(Cert_ID('MyTestCertificate'), @ClearText, @Signature);
select @Signature_len, @RESULT
```

Comment: "Ideally I expect the signature size should be..." why does it matter to you? That is, what problem does having the signature be a certain length solve?

Comment: In my use case, I sign data over SQL server and try to verify it to other host where public key of certificate is accessible. When I try verification by using openssl rsautl, it started complaining about the length of data. 

    openssl rsautl -verify -in signature.bin -inkey public.key -pubin
    RSA operation error
    3071469356:error:0406706C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:756:
 
For SQL Server 2008 it used to work (for 1024 bits key)

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you generate a signature via openssl? Is there an obvious relationship between the resulting bytes there and what SQL is generating?

Comment: I dont have access to private keys, so wont be able to sign data using openssl. However when I tested signing with openssl with 2048 bit key... signature length 256 byte is generated

Comment: In re: access to private keys, can you generate your own certificate with which to test?

Comment: @BenThul I created my own keys still the signature length is coming out as 264 bytes 2048 bit key and 136 bytes for 1024 bit keys (so its always 8 bytes extra). 
also common thing I observe here that signature always starts with 0x01 (whch is not the case for SQL Server 2008).  

Sample signature
    0x0100050204000000CE5F2A45FE3E637609DF95B10B3E1642B56D3C3208EE5769...

Comment: If you use the same certificate on both the file system and in SQL, do you see a relationship in the signatures? The leading 0x0100050204000000 (i.e. the first eight bytes) seems suspicious to me and I'm wondering out loud if the rest of the bytes (in your example, the bytes starting at CE5F) are the actual signature.

Comment: I don't see any relation. I did try stripping first 8 bytes and verifying the signature however it failed. For 1024 bit keys also signature starts with that pattern. The sql method to verify signature returns 1 (signature matches).  So bit confusing or something changes drastically in sql 2017